# Always show packet loss metric

Tags: dota-2, source-engine

In Dota 2 if you input the command `-ping` you'll get an more accurate ping measure and also a packet loss percentage.

Is possible within the source engine to **always display the packet loss** just like  `net_graph`?

Answer (score 1):

It's still net_graph ... here are the settings I use in my autoexec.cfg that fit my resolution:

```
//show net_graph properly in top right corner of screen.
net_graph 1
net_graphinsetbottom 437
net_graphinsetright -80
net_graphproportionalfont 0
```

Comment: Ok, where exactly `net_graph` displays the current packet loss?

Comment: I think its net_graphshowlatency 1 "Draw the ping/packet loss graph." that you are talking about

Comment: if you don't like net_graph 1 you can try net_graph 2 and 3 too.

Answer (score 0):

net_graph isn't an option anymore , there is `dota_hud_netgraph 1` nowadays